# How do you make a byte into a binary number and not to a string in java

Tags: java

When I want to print the binary number of a byte, I have to do:

```
byte byte1 = 16;
String byteString = Integer.toBinaryString(byte1);
System.out.println(byteString);
```

This makes the byte into a string, but when I try to parse it into a byte, it makes it into a base 10 number again, Is there a way to make a byte into a binary number byte, and not to a base-10? I want to make it so that if you printed the byte, it would print the binary.  do you have to tell it to print the Binary every time?

Comment: This code doesn't pass compilation. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: 16 is only a human-readable decimal representation, but in the system it *is* a "binary number byte" already without any conversion.

Comment: What is the expected result of this code?

Comment: "Probably makes the program run slower" Pre-optimization is evil. Why do you want this functionality anyways? Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: If you want to see what a byte looks like in binary, you can do `Integer.toBinaryString()` as you know. It might seem unnecessary to use a `String`, but even if you converted `16` to the `int` `10000`, when you try to print it, it would get converted to a `String` anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear, I want to know if there is a way to make it print the binary representation of the byte every time, instead of having to convert it to a binary string every time, and without making a new string variable to print.

Comment: @codersarecool Why would you need to make a new string variable? `System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(byte1));` would work.

Comment: Anything printed *is* a string. You print text, right? So why is using `toBinaryString()` a problem?

Comment: @codersarecool What would be the purpose of that? On the very basic level you can only print strings (roughly speaking), so if you want to print something, you must convert it to a string first. If you don't want to do the conversion again, you store the result in a variable. If you don't store it in a variable, you have to do the conversion again. There's no third option.

Comment: "when I try to parse it into a byte". I don't see *any* code attempting to parse anything into a byte.

Comment: Yes but is there a way to have the byte print the binary string when called, without having to do .toBinaryString() ?

Comment: Calling `toBinaryString()` is the right way to do it, so we're all confused as to why you want another way.

Comment: Because of programmer efficiency.

Comment: @codersarecool Which means what?

Comment: Being efficient at programming?

Comment: How is that inefficient?

Comment: @codersarecool I've added an answer explaining "efficiency" to you, check it out.

Comment: @codersarecool Java is a verbose language. If you want to be efficient, you must learn several languages and use the one that is most appropriate for a task. But after a time you'll realise that brevity doesn't always increase efficiency, being efficient is more about knowing which tool to use for which task, what to worry about and what to ignore. (Amongst a lot of other things of course.)

Comment: I think these comments have strayed far from the topic, but thanks anyway.  my question is answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know if there is a way to make it print the binary representation of the byte every time, instead of having to convert it to a binary string every time, and without making a new string variable to print.

You don't need a `String` variable because you can just do this:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(a));
```

but there is no way to make the conversion happen automatically without using `toBinaryString`. If this code is too long, you could make a simple method like this

```
public static void printInBinary(int a) {
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(a));
}
```

As you have identified, both approaches will result in unnecessary work if you need to print the same number repeatedly, but you do not need to worry about this. Worrying about stuff like that is a waste of time (99% of the time).

Answer (score 1):

> Because of programmer efficiency.

At physical level, computers do not have the concept of neither "binary" numbers nor "decimal" numbers (I mean, in form of "110011" or "123"). It's all electrical impulses in there. When you are printing a number onto the screen, it ALWAYS has to convert the "impulses" into characters on your screen in one way or another.

When the number is stored in memory as a "number", it is not compatible with neither decimal nor binary representation. Converting the "number" into a "string" of *any* kind requires approximately same amount of computing power.

Let's say you have this code:

```
byte byte1 = 16;
String byteString = Integer.toBinaryString(byte1);
System.out.println(byteString);
System.out.println(byte1);
```

In reality, the operations performed by the cpu would look something like this:

```
String byteString = Integer.toBinaryString(byte1);
String decimalString = toDecimalString(byte1);
System.out.println(byteString);
System.out.println(decimalString);
```

That is, unless you save your number as String already, your CPU has to do extra work to convert it into either decimal or hexadecimal or binary representation. It is just that by default a decimal representation is chosen. And, there is no way to somehow "switch" this default representation neither for one variable nor globally for entire application.

Therefore, you need to convert it to binary every time you want a variable of any numeric type printed on the screen as a character.

Comment: Yes but if you made your number into a string initially... that sort of defeats the purpose of having a computer.

Comment: Yes, however, you should also understand that computer is designed to "compute" as fast as possible, not to "print" as fast as possible. Therefore, all the architecture is designed in such a way, as to make mathematical operations as fast as possible, not printing ones. That's why you can not just print the data it has in memory, the data has to be **converted** every time before being printed. And converting it to binary or decimal is the choice of the programmer (which by default, for Java, is "decimal").

Comment: Oh, I see, so is the string is the only data type able to be printed, the rest are just ideas stored in memory.

Comment: Yes, exactly. And that happens with every programming language and every operating system. It is just that the conversion is inserted automatically, like in case of `System.out.println(byte1)`, but the conversion still happens.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
byte byte1 = 76;
StringBuilder byteString = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 128; i > 0; i /= 2) {
    if ((byte1 & i) == 0) {
        byteString.append(0);
    } else {
        byteString.append(1);
    }
}
System.out.println(byteString);
```

Comment: This looks like a job for a `StringBuilder`, string concatenation in a loop can be costly, especially in Java.

Comment: So you just created your own version of `toBinaryString()`. Congrats, but that has no bearing on anything related to this question.

Answer (score 0):

What about `Byte.parseByte(s, radix)`?

```
System.out.println(Byte.parseByte("10000", 2)); // prints 16
```

Comment: Well, I want it to print the binary when I tell it to print the byte.

Comment: @codersarecool This is an answer to the "when I try to parse it into a byte" issue mentioned in the question. Even though you didn't show any code attempting that, yasd has been nice enough to help you anyway.